# How can I get java jdk to work after I installed it in a specific directory?

Tags: windows, java, virtual-machine, noclassdeffounderror

I am installing jdk on a computer that I do not have admin access to, and used cgywin with cabextract to extract the files from the installer. I then extracted the tools zip into a new directory. However, when I try to run javac from the bin, i get this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

I looked again into the directory, and noticed that tools.jar was missing from JDK/lib when I compared it to the file structure on the java documentation.

I was wondering if missing that jar is causing my problem, or if something else is.

Comment: looks like installation error, uninstall with clean way and reinstall it again

Comment: tools.jar missing would DEFINITELY cause that problem.

Comment: `rt.jar` is not in your class path, that is where java/lang/Object.class is. If Java is installed correctly you won't have that problem.